# wxWidgets AttributeError on editable listctrl

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I have copied an example of an editable ListCtrl from http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/01/04/wxpython-wx-listctrl-tips-and-tricks/ . I have changed *InsertStringItem* and *SetStringItem* to *InsertItem* and *SetItem*. When I try to run this I get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx\lib\mixins\listctrl.py", line 560, in OnLeftDown
    self.OpenEditor(col, row)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx\lib\mixins\listctrl.py", line 568, in OpenEditor
    evt.Index = row
AttributeError: can't set attribute

I am using Python 2.7.10 on Windows 10.

How do I fix this?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because I want to be able to edit a listCtrl field. It's not working.

Comment: It looks like you may be using a Phoenix snapshot of wxPython, is that the case?  Either way, which version?

Comment: Yes, I am using Phoenix 3.0.3.dev2276+1080849 msw (phoenix)

Comment: Try updating it to a newer build.  I added some unittests yesterday for checking those `ListEvent` properties and they passed so it is something that has been changed since the version you are using.

Comment: Thank you. I updated and it works as expected.